# Add spacing between UITextFields in a UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have created a UIAlertController with two text fields, it turned out like this:

[image: screenshot of alert controller]

Is it possible to create some space between them without creating my own pop up view controller?

This is my code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please enter Dish description and price", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: desc)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: price)
```

Comment: You need to create your own if you wish to customize its appearance.

Comment: `UIAlertController` is that what it is – with a very few options to customise it.

Comment: As others mentioned you need to create a custom alertcontroller. Take a look at this  tutorial https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/design-and-code-your-own-uialertview-ec3d8c000f0a

Comment: Hi maybe consider this, really cool PopupDialog and easy to use: https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Comment: I'll consider using that, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController - change size of textfields and add space between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787115/uialertcontroller-change-size-of-textfields-and-add-space-between-them)

Comment: You are correct I tried to find similar question but couldn't find it.
Thanks