# Swift alert custom show and dispense

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I created a custom alert in a viewcontroller, following the guidelines of the most voted answer of that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275840/6196609

I use this to display the alert, it is used as a "loading".

```
let pending = UIAlertController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    […]

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let pending = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("alertaLoad")
    pending.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    pending.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve

    […]

}
```

to show:

```
self.presentViewController(self.pending, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I succeeded in showing it, but I need to terminate it by the viewcontroller that invoked it after the end of my process, not by itself as was done in the example I quoted.
I've tried this but nothing happens.

```
self.pending.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { (vetor) -> Void in
                    […]
                })
```

How could I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `dismiss`on the presenting `UIViewController`, not on the presented one:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    // go on
}
```