# Can we change the height and width of UIAlertController Buttons in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, uialertcontroller

I want to customize the controls of UIAlertviewcontroller in swift and Change the width and height of the Cancel and OK buttons in swift.
Is there any way possible to achieve this?[Just similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utlYw.jpg)

Comment: I have given this link below: -     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379559/custom-alert-uialertview-with-swift

Comment: you can see and check it.

Comment: Like this ->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/utlYw.jpg

Comment: I don't think so. I have tried to change color/tint color of different layers which is working fine, but for control's size better you go with custom... Please update me if you find anything on this.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code : -

//// 
change the height of alert view controller

*

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "hello", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        // hide action sheet
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.80)
    alertController.view.addConstraint(height);
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*

Comment: OP wants to change  width and height of the Cancel and OK buttons not the entire view.

Comment: @Tejveer , my requirement is quite clear, i don't want to change height of alertview only the width and height of buttons