# Remove separators in UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, lines, separator

There is way to remove separators between actions in UIAlert (actionSheet style)?

Comment: Highly unlikely.

Comment: create custom view...

Comment: Not possible with native alert you can use something already available or create something of your own

Comment: iOS is not provide to change the design of `UIAlertView` . You need to make your own custom view for showing the alert .

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it with the system-provided `UIAlertView`.

However, have a look at [this Swift-written repo](https://github.com/krispenney/FCAlertView). It may help you creating a custom alert.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no:(

You can easily create your own following [this](https://medium.com/@aatish.rajkarnikar/how-to-make-custom-alertview-dialogbox-with-animation-in-swift-3-2852f4e6f311) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379559/custom-alert-uialertview-with-swift) tutorials.

I'm sure it will be useful experience for you!

Good luck!

**EDIT**: updated the links.

Comment: The tutorial shows the native alert only and it doesn't answers question in any manner

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar good catch! copied the wrong link. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add UIAlertAction, then there will be no separator. You can add button programmatically by adding subview.