# "cellForRowAtIndexPath" for a tableview inside alertviewcontroller not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertview

I am adding a tableview inside an alertviewcontroller , I have given delegate and datasource to the table. All delegate and datasource methods except cellForRowAtIndexPath are called. I have return a static value for number of rows in section to prevent 0 rows. Still it is occurring.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: So you put a table view inside an alert view controller? This seems **horribly** wrong. I'd strongly suggest creating a custom UI instead.

Comment: @the4kman Exactly I m thinking, i wanted to see the sceen.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @AbhishekMaster It depends what you wanted to achieve. Define your ques properly, it is highly unclear.

Comment: @AbhishekMaster I just did: create a custom UIView with an alert-like appearance. Build your own or use a Pod. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25379559/3151675

Comment: Just want to show tableview in alertview style , and get the row selection result

Comment: @AbhishekMaster Use child container in your main VC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to modify the view hierarchy of a `UIAlertController`.  You’ll either need to create your own view controller that mimics an alert controller or find a framework that does that for you.

To quote the Apple docs:

> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a custom UIViewController, add required functionality and present it as a Form Sheet. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html