# How to change the UIAlertController's width in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Here is one way to change the AlertController's width:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disconnected", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
let width : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 160) 
alertController.view.addConstraint(width)
```

But there will be an error message when running:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ae50 UIView:0x7f9c4473cbf0.width == 270   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002824e0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7f9c460d4e00'Disconnected'.width >= UIView:0x7f9c4473cbf0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00008be00 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7f9c460d4e00'Disconnected'.width == 160   (active)>"

)
```

Is there any other way to change the AlertController's width? Or is there any way to fix the error?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a custom alert view if you want to modify the dimensions of it.

Comment: @TamásSengel Thanks, Tamas. You mean creating a custom UIView?

Comment: Yes, for example. Some other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25379559/3151675

Comment: @TamásSengel OK, this is well noted with thanks.