# How to review or rating Application inside the app - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rating, review

I want to display in-app rating and review popup in my application (i.e like the popup in the attachment below)

[image]

I searched about this functionality and I found that `StoreKit` have this function `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` which display this popup.

What happened is that this function gives me a popup with rating functionality without the ability to write a review choice.

so anyone knows how to display the **write review** choice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please refer to [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379559/custom-alert-uialertview-with-swift ]

Comment: what is the relation between my question and the custom alert?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submit button will navigate to the review page with the stars filled. So there is no option for directly writing reviews on that popup.

> Users will submit a rating through the standardized prompt, and can authenticate with Touch ID to write and submit a review.

Comment: ohh got you! thanks for answering.
so do you mean after the user click on submit for the review this popup will appear?
I can't click on submit now because it's on development environment so I'm not sure about this scenario

Comment: Exactly. It will navigate to the review page but will fill the stars according to the first popup.