# Add UITextView on UIAlertView (iOS, Xamarin) without using any third party lib

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextview, uialertcontroller

I want to display a dialog in iOS and add a `UITextView` to the view of the dialog. The `UITextView` textView has text with clickable links for email,phone and url. I am able to trigger the dialog but only with the title and an ok button. There is no textview being added to the dialog view. I am not sure if the issue here is with the textview or with the way the view is being added to the dialog.

Please check my code below:

```
 UITextView textView = new UITextView();
 textView.Editable = false;
 textView.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.All;
 textView.Message = message;
 var dlg = UIAlertController.Create(Title ?? String.Empty, null, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
 dlg.View.AddSubview(textView);
 dlg.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(OkText, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => Submit()));                

 var top = Utils.GetTopViewController();
 top.PresentViewController(dlg, animated: true, completionHandler: null);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285750/adding-a-custom-view-to-a-alert-view

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you need a custom popup view to finish what you need, I write a sample for you, this is the code:

This is the ViewController.cs:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (new UITapGestureRecognizer (() => {
            CustomPopUpView cpuv = new CustomPopUpView (new CoreGraphics.CGSize (300, 200));
            cpuv.PopUp (true,delegate{
                Console.WriteLine("cpuv will close");
            });
        }));
    }
}
```

And this is the CustomPopUpView.cs:

```
public class CustomPopUpView : UIView
{
    public delegate void PopWillCloseHandler ();
    public event PopWillCloseHandler PopWillClose;

    private UIVisualEffectView effectView = new UIVisualEffectView (UIBlurEffect.FromStyle (UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark));
    private UIButton btnClose = new UIButton (UIButtonType.System);

    public CustomPopUpView (CGSize size)
    {
        nfloat lx = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - size.Width) / 2;
        nfloat ly = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - size.Height) / 2;
        this.Frame = new CGRect (new CGPoint (lx, ly), size);

        effectView.Alpha = 0;

        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        nfloat btnHeight = 40;
        btnClose.SetTitle ("Close", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnClose.Frame = new CGRect (0, this.Frame.Height - btnHeight, this.Frame.Width, btnHeight);
        btnClose.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            Close();
        };
        this.AddSubview (btnClose);
    }

    public void PopUp (bool animated = true, Action popAnimationFinish = null)
    {
        UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        effectView.Frame = window.Bounds;
        window.EndEditing (true);
        window.AddSubview (effectView);
        window.AddSubview (this);

        if (animated) {
            Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (0.1f, 0.1f);
            UIView.Animate (0.15, delegate {
                Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (1, 1);
                effectView.Alpha = 0.8f;
            },delegate {
                if(null != popAnimationFinish)
                    popAnimationFinish ();
            });
        } else {
            effectView.Alpha = 0.8f;
        }
    }

    public void Close (bool animated = true)
    {
        if (animated) {
            UIView.Animate (0.15, delegate {
                Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (0.1f, 0.1f);
                effectView.Alpha = 0;
            }, delegate {
                this.RemoveFromSuperview();
                effectView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                if(null != PopWillClose) PopWillClose ();
            });
        } else {
            if(null != PopWillClose) PopWillClose ();
        }
    }
}
```

You can just add anything you want to this CustomPopUpView, or you can inherit it and create your own popup.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: when i close the pop up there is still small white area remains on the screen i changed the `Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (0.1f, 0.1f);` to `Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (0.01f, 0.01f);`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to remove it, you should remove it when close animation finished, I have edited my code, thanks for you remind.@FahadRehman

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can add a UITextField in a UIAlertViewController

```
  var alert = UIAlertController.Create(Enter OTP, "", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddTextField((obj) =>
            {
                obj.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
                obj.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
                obj.Placeholder = "OTP";

            });

            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Submit", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (obj) => 
            {
                chargeReference = reference;
                statusValue = alert.TextFields[0].Text;
                CompleteFunding();
            }));
            PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
```

I hope this helps