# How to create custom alert view for ios on xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, customization

I need to create custom alertview programmatically on C# for Xamarin.iOS on. Alert must contain image like this example.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBCv0.png)

Comment: I have post a sample code for you, you need try to finish the detail by yourself. @Pavel Chehov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a custom pop up, I have wrote a sample for others, it contains a custom UIView you can use it and add anything you want on it.

[Sample custom pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132860/add-uitextview-on-uialertview-ios-xamarin-without-using-any-third-party-lib/39136003#39136003)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you! It's what I need.