# How can I build custom UIAlertController in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am currently dealing with the design which cannot be build using UIAlertController. How can I customize it?

Comment: Please read [following help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can help you better.

Comment: Hi, have you solved it , you can detail explain in question.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, did it with the help of TelerikUI

Comment: @NIshank Great, you can share solution in answer .If my answer be helpful , thanks for voting up in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the AlertView, the recommended way is to use it as it, but if you really want to create your own Alert modal, you should use a ViewController. The Apple [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) state:

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

So, you basically have to create a new Alert that inherits from UIViewController that's displayed as a popup, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132860/add-uitextview-on-uialertview-ios-xamarin-without-using-any-third-party-lib/39136003#39136003)

Answer (score 0):

First you need clearly explain which effect you want in question.This document [Displaying Alerts in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/alerts) maybe helpful .

```
okayCancelButton.TouchUpInside += ((sender, e) => {

    //Create Alert
    var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Alert Title", "Choose from two buttons", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    //Add Actions
    okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine ("Okay was clicked")));
    okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine ("Cancel was clicked")));

    //Present Alert
    PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, null);
});
```

Comment: What is the declaration type is OkayCancelButton?

Comment: @MarkWardell Using `UIAlertAction.Create` to define `Button` , you can have a look at my shared documnet .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not much customization available for UIAlertController. 
You have to use Telerik UI (TKAlert View).
And then on that TKAlert View you can add your custom view.